# how can i Add commission_pct column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I put the schema manually, but there is no commission_pct column. How can i add it?

I can't find commission_pct data anywhere...

plz help me :(

````
select  employee_id as 사원번호,
            first_name || ' ' || last_name as 사원명,
            nvl( salary + (salary * commission_pct), salary)*12 as 연봉,
            department_id as 부서번호
    from employees
    where department_id in(30,50,60) and
        nvl( salary + (salary * commission_pct), salary)*12 >= 20000 and
        nvl( salary + (salary * commission_pct), salary)*12 <= 60000
    order by 부서번호, 연봉 desc;```
````

ORA-00904: "COMMISSION_PCT": 부적합한 식별자
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier

Comment: alter table
   employees
add commission number(7,2) NOT NULL;

Comment: Unfortunately we do not know your model and reason why you expect this column to be in a table. Please, provide a table definition and describe what you want to achieve

Comment: Are you saying, you thought that the column `COMMISSION_PCT` was in the employees table, but it is not, and now you think it's in another table, but you don't know which? You can look for the column in your database with `select * from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'COMMISSION_PCT'`. If you are not allowed to query `dba_tab_cols` you can try `all_tab_cols` instead or `user_tab_cols` as a last straw.

Comment: If you are working with Oracle's HR schema, then `commission_pct` should be in `employees`. In that case: who set that database up? You have not specified a schema in your query (i.e. `hr.employees` instead of a mere `employees`), so you are working with your own schema. Are you logged in as hr? If not, is the database installed in your schema or is your employees actually just a view to hr.employees? And if so, are all columns in that view? Maybe `commission_pct` was omitted in the view.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of strange; how are you supposed to work with column that doesn't exist? Are you sure you're connected to right schema and have all tables you should?

As of your question, you'd add a new column into a table with `alter table`. Here's how: my `employees` table is a dummy one, it does not represent your table.

```
SQL> desc employees
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID                               NOT NULL NUMBER
 FIRST_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 HIRE_DATE                                 NOT NULL DATE
 SALARY                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)

SQL> alter table employees add commision_pct number;

Table altered.
```

To set a value, you'd `update` table as

```
SQL> update employees set commision_pct = 15;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```